# Writing Python script to automate llvm code coverage test

Tags: python, bash, llvm, code-coverage

It's my first day coding in Python, and I am having a rough time with some automation. I have a program (./main) that takes in .txt files via input redirection ("./main < 1.txt"). I need to run it with 1000 different txt files (1.txt to 1000.txt) and use llvm to output merged code coverage data to a file coverage.txt. In bash, the following commands are successful for two files:

```
clang++ -fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping main.cpp -o main
-LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="1.profraw" ./main < 1.txt
-LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="2.profraw" ./main < 2.txt
llvm-profdata merge -sparse 1.profraw 2.profraw -o main.profdata
llvm-cov show ./main -instr-profile=main.profdata main.cpp > coverage.txt
```

My goal is to script this in Python and loop to create and merge all the .profraw files. I've tried many variations of the following approach with no success:

```
subprocess.call(["clang++", "-fprofile-instr-generate", "-fcoverage-mapping", "main.cpp", "-o", "main"])

i = 1
while i <= 1000:
    inputFilename = str(i) + ".txt"
    outputFilename = "\"" + str(i) + ".profraw\""
    llvmCommand = "LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="   
    cmd = [llvmCommand, outputFilename, "./main", "<", inputFilename]
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    p.communicate()
    i += 1
```

I haven't moved on to the merge step yet because this does NOT generate any .profraw files. It also doesn't generate any errors messages in Spyder or when run from the terminal.

Thanks in advance for any help; I know that this is basic but I have spent hours on it without luck.

Edit: Attempting Henk's approach:

```
i = 1
while i <= 1000:
    inputFilename = ''.join([str(i), ".txt"])
    outputFilename = ''.join(['"', str(i), '.profraw"'])
    llvmCommand = ''.join(["LLVM_PROFILE_FILE=", outputFilename])  
    cmd = [llvmCommand, "./main", "<", inputFilename]
    sp = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = sp.communicate()
    i += 1
```

Here is the error I receive (even when I hardcode the absolute filepath):

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="1.profraw"': 'LLVM_PROFILE_FILE="1.profraw"'
```

Comment: Mixing ' and " strategically can help you prevent escaping them. In this case:  ' " ' + str(i) + '.profraw" '

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this approach, you could see what (if anything) went wrong in the stdout and stderr.

```
sp = subprocess.Popen([executable, arg1, arg2], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = sp.communicate()
```

Comment: Thank you! The error parameter is very helpful. I have posted an update with the new code and the error I now receive. It seems that in the call to subprocess.Popen() the .profraw output path is not recognized. Do you have any hunches as to where the error could be? I have tried with the full file path but get the same error.

Comment: You could include the absolute path. os.getcwd() will give you the current working directory. You could prepend it to the input and output filenames. Or simply hard-code it when quick-and-dirty suffices.